# Mongoose with replica set - where is reading from?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

Im using Mongoose as my ODM and now moving from single node to Replicaset.

I wonder what's happen beyond the sense?

I guess that writing operations goes automatically to the master but what about reading? Is mongoose makes it also to master ONLY or (randomally) read from different secondaries?

Also, is there any ability to configure Mongoose to read from specific nodes for all queries or maybe even just for particular queries?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change default read preferences of MongoDB replicaset. By default, all read/write will go to primary node but these can be routed to secondaries or which ever node is closer to client in term of ping time.

Please see comprehensive documentation about [read preferences](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) in MongoDB replicaset.

Comment: oh. great, so everything is transparent the clients using the Replica Set (Mongoose etc.) - and Mongo server know to manage all rules by itself.. right?

Comment: Yes, driver will route queries to appreciate replica set members transparently.